# Compile Error: CS1056: Unexpected character '$' when publishing Asp.net webforms to godaddy shared server

Tags: webforms, shared-hosting

I'm trying to update a site publishing to GoDaddy shared server and I'm getting this error:

> *Compiler Error Message: CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
>   Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3761.0
>   for C# 5
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240*

I have tried with the GoDaddy TechSupport, unsuccessfully as they keep saying the error is on the script of the site, but the site works perfectly on my localhost in visual studio 2019, to discard compatibility version issues, GoDaddy says it supports the latest c# version on a shared server and asp.net 4.7 plus.

Now, this error is fixed if I remove the code using the "$",... but this cannot be correct.

My web config tagets 4.7.2 frameworks and has this as well:

I just wants to clarified that I'm a self-taught beginner asp.net programmer and probably must be missing something that could be quite apparent to others, so I humbly ask for help to anyone with far more expertise in the subject

Comment: Looks like your hoster is using an older version of the C# compiler only supporting C# version 5, but [the string interpolation using the _"$"_ sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is a feature that was introduced in C# version 6. Can you switch to a newer compiler version? Otherwise I think you'll have to use another approach for interpolating strings, for example using the [string.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Comment: From the error message, it seems that your hoster still use older version. Maybe you can contact them to install newest version.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue with my site hosted with GoDaddy.